# Django Admin: Random key in TabularInline repetitious, not random

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm creating a coupon generator for handing out "get $10 of service free if you sign up using this code."  The user base is very small, and the likelihood of passing out more than ten coupons at a time is unlikely.

When creating a new marketing campaign, the administrator is given five coupons in a TabularInline, with the option to create more via the "Add another Coupon" button.  But coupons 6 and beyond all have the exact same random code as coupon 5; it looks as if Django isn't actually asking for a new example object from the server, but just duplicating the last one it saw.

The code to do this is:

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign)
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 32, blank=False, null=False, default=generate_code)
    redeemed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True, blank = True)
```

Where `generate_code()` is a function that, well, generates a random string.  It seems to me that Django's admin ought to honor the `default` setting of its own Field classes, and it does... for the first *n* generated by the admin server-side, but not for those built by client request.

Is there a way to have Django create the objects on the server and fetch them?  Will I have to hack my own page to create the codes inline?  Or is there a smarter way to go about this?

Comment: Sounds like those random coupons are created by custom code that you wrote and not by Django. Why use inlines for this at all? Is there any other functionality other than the random generated coupons? Maybe you should consider creating a custom built ajax function that creates and displays newly generated coupons instead.

Comment: @dan-klasson: I updated the question to show the breakdown.  Django`s admin isn't honoring the `default` argument of a `models.Field` correctly.  I'm trying to figure out if I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Add another" link in the django inlines is client side javascript. That's probably why it takes the last generated value. If you want it to return a random server side string you would have to override it and implement your own ajax function. You could also generate it client side with javascript.

Comment: Well, suck.  That's a nasty break point in Django-- programmatic defaults ought to be honored.